# GUI Modification Help vb.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms, user-interface, .net-4.0

I created a Perfect Launcher with a minimize option but not in the taskbar it minimizes in desktop so i want to change the gui of its title bar of minimize form...
Perfect Launcher not having control box and i created a custom minimize button.

[image: Change title bar color, look & shape]

I want to Change its classic look of title bar and make it more attractive and change its color, look & shape...

I am using:

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Me.ShowInTaskbar = False

End Sub

End Class
```